# ORACLE: Using DECODE to solve "Divide by zero" error but need to get result to 2nd decimal place

Tags: oracle

```
select 
  A,
  B,
  NVL((A-B) / DECODE(A, 0, NULL, B), 0) as result

from table1
where NVL((A-B) / DECODE(A, 0, NULL, B), 0) as result > 0.5
```

I figure out how to solve "Divide by zero" error using DECODE
But not sure how to incorporate with CAST,FLOAT,ROUND to get the division result to the 2nd plance

With above code, I get integer result

```
A     B    Result(A-B)/B
1500  700  1 
3000  0    blank or null
```

I need to get the result to the 2nd decimal place which the result is greater than 1

```
A     B    Result(A-B)/B 
1500  700  1.14
3000  0    blank or null
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't even have `NVL()` and I don't see what you're trying to do with `DECODE()`? Your queries make no sense at all.

Comment: Changed to ORACLE question. Im trying to solve "Divide by zero" error using
 DECODE() to distinguish denominator (B) value = 0

Comment: without using DECODE(), I get "Divide by zero" error when value of the B is zero 
to calculate (A-B)/B

Comment: Try `(A-B)/NULLIF(B, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

There are various options; use `decode`, `case` or `nullif`, e.g.

```
SQL> with test (a, b) as
  2    (select 1500, 700 from dual union all
  3     select 3000,   0 from dual
  4    )
  5  select a, b,
  6    (a-b) / decode(b, 0, null, b) as result_1,
  7    --
  8    (a-b) / case when b = 0 then null else b end as result_2,
  9    --
 10    (a-b) / nullif(b, 0) as result_3
 11  from test;

         A          B   RESULT_1   RESULT_2   RESULT_3
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      1500        700 1,14285714 1,14285714 1,14285714
      3000          0

SQL>
```

As you can see, by default result *does* contain decimals, which means that - if you don't see any - it is about settings in your environment and/or tool you use.

If you want to restrict number of decimals to 2, usually we use `round` function (another *popular* option is `trunc`):

```
  5  select a, b,
  6    round((a-b) / decode(b, 0, null, b), 2) as result_1
  7  from test;

         A          B   RESULT_1
---------- ---------- ----------
      1500        700       1,14
      3000          0
```

---

If you used SQL*Plus (as I did), it offers various `SET` commands; one of them lets you specify `numformat` which then handles it:

```
SQL> set numformat 999g990d00
<snip>
  5  select a, b,
  6    (a-b) / decode(b, 0, null, b) as result_1
  7  from test;

          A           B    RESULT_1
----------- ----------- -----------
   1.500,00      700,00        1,14
   3.000,00        0,00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the calculation (including `ROUND`) into the `DECODE`:

```sql
SELECT A,
       B,
       DECODE(B, 0, 0, ROUND((A-B) / B), 2)) as result
FROM   table1
WHERE  DECODE(B, 0, 0, ROUND((A-B) / B), 2)) > 0.5
```

or, if you do not want to write the `DECODE` statement twice, then use an inline view to filter:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT A,
         B,
         DECODE(B, 0, 0, ROUND((A-B) / B), 2)) as result
  FROM   table1
)
WHERE  result > 0.5
```